# Is there a configuration file like matplotlibrc in Plots.jl?

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

I try to unify my figures formats across different files. I do not want to use PyPlot.jl.
Is there a configuration file as matplotlibrc in Python? Or some other alternative way that can make me to write these format into a file without changing much about my figures code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (I haven't used `matplotlib` in ages, so not sure what the matplotlibrc file exactly does) you want to specify default settings for your plots in Plots.jl.

When using Plots in a running Julia session, you can use the `default` function:

```
julia> default(color = "red", linewidth = 10)
```

sets default arguments for subsequent `plot` commands.

If you want these defaults to be automatically available in every Julia session you can create a startup file at `~/.julia/config/startup.jl` and set an environment variable there:

```
PLOTS_DEFAULTS = Dict(:color=> 10, :linewidth => 2)
```

will have the same effect as the call to `default` above, but will happen automatically once you start Julia.

This is discussed in the docs [here](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/install/#Initialize).